# Inserting key value pair array in to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

Hello quick question for you guys/gals

I have a javascript object that displays as follows in the console.

```
Object { 10= "a@a.com", 18="b@b.com", 20="c@c.com"}
```

Passing this object to the backend CI Controller thru AJAX I've created the following function with CI.

```
function NewEMail(){
 //this is the array coming from ajax
 $test = $this -> input -> post('sendValue');
 print_r($test);

 if(is_array($test)){
  foreach($test as $t){
  //Insert the values in to the db from here.
  }
 }
}
```

the response from php for the print_r is as follows

```
Array([10] => a@a.com [18] => b@b.com [20] => c@c.com)
```

I would like to push each element and value to a new row as follows.

**EMAIL_TABLE**

```
| id | cus_id | email   |  
| 1  | 10     | a@a.com |  
| 2  | 18     | b@b.com |   
| 3  | 20     | c@c.com |
```

Where the ***'id'*** is auto incremented how ever **'cus_id'** and **'email'** are read and stored from the array.

Any help or directions to helping me solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for reading,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set id as an auto_increment primary key column in your table.

```
create table email (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    cus_id int unsigned,
    email varchar(50)
);

insert into email (cus_id, email) values ('$cusid', '$email');
```

id will then take care of itself, all you have to do is leave it alone when inserting.

PHP code to do this in a loop:

```
foreach ($test as $cusid => $email) {
    $querystring = "insert into users (cus_id, email) values ('$cusid', '$email')";
    myqsli_query($querystring);
}
```

Comment: I understand that it increments on its own and that's not what I am asking in the question. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for the php code to do that. Hold on, I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: There we go. You can actually assign both the key and value to variables in a foreach loop.

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated, is it not?

Comment: @DiMono dont be confused with `mysqli` ! - notice the "i" at the end, however as you say `mysql_` is deprecated, you should youse MySQLi or PDO - however PDO is more portable, so use just PDO... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$test = $this->input->post('sendValue');

if( is_array($test) ){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($test as $cusid => $email) {
        $data[] = array('cus_id' => $cusid, 'email' => $email);
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('tablename', data);
}
```